# Change content of Html page on the 'fly' in Firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

When user click on the button in toolbar of Firefox I need to change content 
of the current active html page. In standart]d implementation it's look like this :

```
function injectNewContent() {

 var pageHtml =
            [
                "<html>",
                "<head>",
                "</head>",
                "<frameset cols='270,*' frameborder='0'>",
                "<frame name='frameI' src='http://www.123.com/default.html'>",
                "<frame name='frameII' src='" + document.location + "'>",
                "<noframes>",
                "<body>", 
                "noframes",
                "</body>",
                "</noframes>",
                "</frameset>",
                "</html>"
            ];

 var fullPageHtml = "";

 for (var i in pageHtml)
 {
     fullPageHtml += pageHtml[i];
 }

 window.document.write(fullPageHtml);
}
```

What I need to change in this code to get same functionality ?

```
 var windowMediator = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1'].
                      getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
 var recentWindow = windowMediator.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");

 recentWindow. ???
```

Or may be I do something wrong ?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to go looking for the browser window, your button is already sitting on one. To access the content area of the current tab simply use `window.content`. This should do what you want:

```
var doc = window.content.document;
doc.open("text/html", true);
doc.write(fullPageHtml);
doc.close();
```

Though personally I would rather assign HTML code to `doc.documentElement.innerHTML`.